# Can I rightfully name my opened file a stream if at some point I move its file-pointer backward?

Tags: assembly, stream, dos, terminology, file-pointer

Quoting from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/files-and-streams?view=msvc-170

> Before you can perform many of the operations on a file, the file must be opened. Opening a file associates it with a stream, ...

I am writing an assembly program where I will be reading from a file. I'd like to treat the file as a stream, reading a byte at a time and halting once the end-of-file marker comes by. On occasion, I could be setting the file-pointer back and now I'm wondering if this behavior is stream-like? I've always felt that once a byte gets out of a stream, it is out forever.
I have no problem with setting the file-pointer forward as that is the same as just reading some number of bytes but not doing any useful work on them.

Comment: No, the orientation refers to byte or wide. See previous sentence that you did not quote. See also [Byte and wide streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/byte-and-wide-streams?view=msvc-170) linked in the, erm, _See also_ section.

Comment: Please quote all relevant content, and not just selective text that omits important details (like the sentence that you left out that answers your question). Also, opening a file associates it with a stream - that stream doesn't get turned on and off depending on what you're doing. As long as you have the file open, it is associated with that stream.

Comment: @KenWhite "that answers your question" That's one problem then, I don't immediately think of 'byte' and 'wide' as being an 'orientation'.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that the language is archaic.

Comment: Yes, but the prior sentences clearly establish what they use the term for: _"the stream is byte oriented (a byte stream) or wide oriented (a wide stream)"_

Comment: @Jester After reading it a few times more, I begin to see that my issue with the term 'orientation' is moot. Probably best to remove it then from the post?

Comment: Yeah, was just about to comment that the general terminology question of "stream" being compatible with rewinding seems totally orthogonal to your question about MS's "orientation" terminology.  And that's still a reasonable question.  C stdio uses "stream" terminology for `FILE*`.  Those might or might not support `fseek`, but even if not, they do support `ungetc` (at least at the library level; I think there might be a POSIX or Linux system call that can unget at least 1 character from some kinds of open file descriptors like a pipe or socket.)

Comment: A rewindable stream can be implemented in terms of a non-rewindable stream, and vice versa.  So to some point of view (e.g. consumption of these), the two can be considered equivalent (modulo real world issues like concurrency, file handle duplication, stream writing while reading, etc..).